# How to seperate entire rows into new data frames using if-statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame `df` that looks something like this:

```
Date         Company         MarketCap
2000-01-31   Company one     1000
2000-02-28   Company one     2000
2000-03-31   Company one     3000
2000-01-31   Company two     2500
2000-02-28   Company two     3000
2000-03-31   Company two     3500
2000-01-31   Company three   1500
2000-02-28   Company three   1800
2000-03-31   Company three   1100
```

I need an if-statement that does the following:

```
If(df$MarketCap >= median(df$MarketCap){
  BigCap <- df[all the rows that have a market cap >= median(df$MarketCap)
}
```

Put in words;
For each row of `df$MarketCap`, I want to check if the market caps are greater than or equal to the median market cap of `df$MarketCap`. All rows containing market caps greater than or equal to the median market cap of `df$MarketCap` should make up a new data frame, `BigCap`.

The new data frame `BigCap` should thus be like this:

`BigCap`:

```
Date         Company         MarketCap
2000-02-28   Company one     2000
2000-03-31   Company one     3000
2000-01-31   Company two     2500
2000-02-28   Company two     3000
2000-03-31   Company two     3500
```

I feel like this should be easy to acheive using an if-statement, but I haven't had any success this far (not by looking at similar questions at SO either). I appreciate all the help I can get.

Note, my real df is a lot larger than the example provided here, where I have 360 dates and over 2000 companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like CPak's answer but if you need the separate `data.frames`, this works:

```
df <- data.frame(date = rep(Sys.Date() - c(60,30,0), 3), comp = rep(1:3, each = 3),
             cap = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 1500, 1800, 1100))

for (i in unique(as.character(df$date))) {
  med <- median(df$cap[df$date == i])
  assign(paste0("smallCap", format(as.Date(i), "%b")),
         df[df$date == i & df$cap < med, ])
  assign(paste0("bigCap", format(as.Date(i), "%b")),
         df[df$date == i & df$cap >= med, ])
}
```

**EDIT:** in comments, OP asked for a data frame for a specific month.

For a given month in a specific year, say Oct 2017:

```
# first calculate median
med <- median(df$cap[format(df$date, "%Y-%m") == "2017-10"])
# subset df
BigCapOct <- df[format(df$date, "%Y-%m") == "2017-10" & df$cap >= med, ]
```

For the month of October *across all years*:

```
med <- median(df$cap[format(df$date, "%m") == "10"])
BigCapOct <- df[format(df$date, "%m") == "10" & df$cap >= med, ]
```

Comment: I'll try your answer to see if I can make it work. Note that I have now edited my question a bit, in order to make it easier to understand (and perhaps to solve)

Comment: Your edited question now only needs `BigCap <- df[df$MarketCap >= median(df$MarketCap, na.rm = T), ]`

Comment: Thank you, that works :) I was certain I would need an if- and/or for-statement. 

What if, as in my original question, I only wanted to do this for certain dates. That is, I want to make a BigCapJan for all market caps in January that is greater than or equal to the median market cap for January. Is there an easy way to implement that into your solution?

I have tried using
`BigCapJan <- df[df$MarketCap[stri_detect_fixed(df$Date, "2000-01")] >= median(df$MarketCap[stri_detect_fixed(df$Date, "2000-01")], na.rm = T), ]` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I created `SmallCap` and `LargeCap`, which is a list of data.frames that contain either observations that are `< median(MarketCap)` or `>= median(MarketCap)`. Each entry of the list is a separate Date.

```
library(dplyr)
SmallCap <- df %>%
             group_by(Date) %>%
           filter(MarketCap < median(MarketCap)) %>%
             split(.$Date)

# $`1`
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [1]
        # Date     Company MarketCap
      # <fctr>      <fctr>     <int>
# 1 2000-01-31 Company_one      1000

# $`2`
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [1]
        # Date       Company MarketCap
      # <fctr>        <fctr>     <int>
# 1 2000-02-28 Company_three      1800

# $`3`
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [1]
        # Date       Company MarketCap
      # <fctr>        <fctr>     <int>
# 1 2000-03-31 Company_three      1100

LargeCap <- df %>%
         group_by(Date) %>%
           filter(MarketCap >= median(MarketCap)) %>%
             split(.$Date)

# $`2000-01-31`
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [1]
        # Date       Company MarketCap
      # <fctr>        <fctr>     <int>
# 1 2000-01-31   Company_two      2500
# 2 2000-01-31 Company_three      1500

# $`2000-02-28`
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [1]
        # Date     Company MarketCap
      # <fctr>      <fctr>     <int>
# 1 2000-02-28 Company_one      2000
# 2 2000-02-28 Company_two      3000

# $`2000-03-31`
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [1]
        # Date     Company MarketCap
      # <fctr>      <fctr>     <int>
# 1 2000-03-31 Company_one      3000
# 2 2000-03-31 Company_two      3500
```